# How do I automate part of visually checking and signing off on 2,000 urls?

Tags: automation

I have a couple thousand URLs to the same page (just different parameters). I need some way to automate loading one URL at a time into a browser or view. After looking at a page to make sure it is okay, I would then press "Good" or "Bad". After that the next page in the list would replace the old one. When done I would have a list of bad urls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write a HTML page with to text areas, two buttons and a a `100%` width inline frame.

- Past the list of URLs into the first text area.
- Label the buttons `good` and `bad`.

  - If `good` gets clicked, eliminate the current URL from the first text area and load the next URL in the inline frame.
  - If `bad` gets clicked, do the same, but also add the current URL to the second text area.

Comment: Grabbed some localStorage, jQuery, and repetitive labor and got it working. Thanks.